# Yii2: How to show SQL results?

Tags: sql, postgresql, model-view-controller, yii2

I want to show the result of this SQL query execution in a **view**:

```
$results = Yii::$app->getDb()->createCommand('SELECT * FROM colors')->queryAll();
$people = print_r($results);
<?= $people ?>
```

But it always shows: `1`

The results should be a table with **3 columns and 10 rows**. So I don't know why it shows `1`. I tried with different tables but always shows the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depend of your need  you

QueryALL return All rows of the query result.
 Each array element is an array representing a row of data

so you could simple iterate over you  $result

```
foreach($result as $key => $row){
  echo  $row['column1'] . '<br />' ; 
  echo  $row['column2'] . '<br />' ; 
  ....
}
```

otherwise you can use the queru for build a sqlDataProvider and the manage the models show with widget  (eg: gridView)

Answer (score 1):

wrong usage of `print_r`. [see this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php). did you mean:

```
$people = print_r($results, true);
```

or just use `var_dump` to avoid confusion.
`$results` already contains your rows.

Answer (score 0):

This way you'll see this array $results.

```
$results = Yii::$app->getDb()->createCommand('SELECT * FROM colors')->queryAll();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($results);
exit;
```